# Asp.NET MVC 4 WebApi Upgrade - RC to 4.0.30506.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I'm running into an issue that many others seemed to have back when the first production release Asp.NET WebApi was introduced and people were upgrading to it from the release candidate edition...

I've been day's trying every solution I found posted on the web with no luck, though I have a much better understanding of the situation now, and think I've narrowed down the problem.

Specifically, it appears that my app (weather its deployed to my local IIS server, or run in the development server) is using the older System.Web.Http assembly.

The very second line of the Application_Start() method fails with an exception

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    **WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);**
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

which calls the Register method from the template-included WebApiConfig.cs file/class:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

where the call config.Routes.MapHttpRoute() causes the following exception:

```
Method not found: 'System.Web.Http.Services.DependencyResolver System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration.get_ServiceResolver()'.

Server stack trace: 
at System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.<.cctor>b__0()
at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
at System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.<.cctor>b__0()
at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
at System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.get_Configuration()
at MvcApplication2.WebApiApplication.Application_Start() 
in C:\Projects\TestArea\ASP_MVC\4\MvcApplication2\Global.asax.cs:line 21
```

Things I've done so far were:

- Reinstall all versions of .NET
- Remove System.Web.Http from GAC
- Made sure the project references pointed to the WebApi directories, and not the os's .NET assemblies
- Made sure the project references were set to "Copy Local"
- Removed IIS's temp files from c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\ and c:\inetpub
- Ran c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe
- Updated all WebApi related packages through NuGet
- Stopped and started IIS and Site
- Rebooted

The ServiceResolver method doesn't exist in the normal .NET System.Web.Http, only in the WebApi version of System.Web.Http, that's why I figured its referencing the wrong assembly.

I'm just don't know what else to do. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked that the project is refering to System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll and version 4?

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: Yes, I verified all references.

Comment: Sorry, I added to post: Method not found: 'System.Web.Http.Services.DependencyResolver System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration.get_ServiceResolver()'.

Comment: Are you using dependency injection?

Comment: No, no dependency injection. This is a bare-bone, Web-Api project from the Asp.NET MVC 4 template.

Comment: You don't mention uninstalling the MVC4 and WebApi nuget packages, did you do this?  Did you manually delete all the files from obj and bin directories?  Are you sure that the IIS site is pointing to the right directory?

Comment: We'll for the project build directory, I created this project at hand today, after all updates, and removing RC (as far as I know its gone). IIS is configured with a virtual directory that the site gets deployed to. Are there other config settings for directories I should check ?

Comment: Are you deploying to a separate server?  Does it work in the development server or IIS Express?

Comment: I've tried both, the built in VS development server (cassini), and an IIS Express server that is local to the machine I'm developing on. I get the same exception on each.

Comment: The ServiceResolver method doesn't exist in the normal .NET System.Web.Http, only in the WebApi version of System.Web.Http, that's why I figured its referencing the wrong assembly.

Comment: Yes, I know.  I was asking about whether it worked in development servers because that helps isolate the problem.  You didn't answer my question though, are you deploying to a separate server, or are you deploying to a folder on your local IIS?

Comment: Deploying to a folder on my local IIS (I posted two comments, its in the 2nd one above, sorry).

Comment: Look in this location C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Packages (if you have a 32 bit machine, remove the (x86)) and check the version of the System.WebApi.Core package

Comment: Also, you say you removed it from the GAC, you do know there are several GAC locations, right?  Did you do it manually (deleting the file) or did you remove it via the gacutil tool?

Comment: I didn't know about  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Packages, and there are a ton of old RC (4.0.20710.0) files in there, and no 4.0.30506 files. This could be it. I used the gacutil tool, and wasn't aware of multiple GAC location.

Comment: 20710.0 is the correct version of MVC4 and WebApi. System.Web.Http is not a part of the core .NET runtime, and there should not be anything named that in the GAC, or in any of the system folders.  As you can see here, the RC was version 20505 - http://nuget.org/packages/aspnetmvc - This folder is the location used by the tools when you create a new MVC project, it uses the packages from this location.

Comment: That link is to the previous version, this is the latest http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc, however either should work, b/c they're both newer than the RC... Do I need .NET 4.5 ?

Comment: Sorry, that was the MVC link, there's a separate WebApi package, but it's the same version numbers.  I don't believe they changed the version numbers of the DLL, just the package, and rolled everything up.  No, you don't need .net 4.5

Comment: Ahh.. ok, it looks like 30506 does have some changes, to bring it in line with the VS 2012.2 Web Update.  Still, I asked before.. but did you check the version of System.Web.Http in the bin folder of your app, what is that version?

Comment: Then there is no reason this should be happening.  When you start the app in the debugger, check the output window and see which version of System.Web.Http is loaded

Comment: bin/System.Web.Http.dll version: 4.0.20710.0, even though the project reference is pointing to the 4.0.3 file, and its set to "Copy Local", and after a clean/rebuild, its still 4.0.2 (if this is having stale issues, I can find the OS issues plausible, lol).

Comment: Uhh, I don't know how :(

Comment: When you start the debugger, there is a tab at the bottom that says "Output", look through this for the output that refers to System.Web.Http.

Comment: I found it in Debug->Windows->Modules. Its 4.0.20710.0 as well !?!

Comment: Try deleting all the .NET temp files in C:\Users\(your user name)\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Comment: System.Web.Http.WebHost was still in GAC. I just removed with gacutil, verified that the WebApi module was being used, and now get a new exceptoin! **Could not load type 'System.Net.Http.Formatting.DefaultContentNegotiator' from assembly 'System.Net.Http.Formatting**

Comment: Oh, and System.Net.Http.Formatting is in GAC...

Comment: Oh nice, it works man, your help got me through this man... If you want, put any of these comments as your answer, and I'll accept it in two days and add some bounty points to it (like 50ish). It was soo worth it. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Samus found the answer himself, I will just post it here as the official answer.

I believe the solution is to check the Output window for various DLL's that are loaded, look for versions that are still using the RC version, find their location and remove them.

In his case, it was because the RC apparently added some DLL's to the GAC (this is no longer done in the release version of MVC4, as they are all bin-deployed).